# Set state from another component React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have the following structure in *index.js* :

```
<MyAppBar // + properties/>
 <Route path={path} component={Login}/>
```

*MyAppBar.js*

```
 class MyAppBar extends React.Component {

state = {
  auth: false,
  anchorElement: null
};

handleLogin(){
  this.setState({auth:true});
}

//another code
//end component

export default withStyles(styles)(MyAppBar)
```

I want to update *MyAppBar* state *auth* flag to be *true* from within the *Login* component action handler (i.e. *handleLogin*), but I do not know how.

I've tried with importing *MyAppBar* (all component) on the *Login* page, but it says that

```
MyAppBar.handleLogin();
```

is not a function... Thank you!

Thank you!

Comment: You can do that with the new React context api [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#api). Basically, you should wrap your `MyAppBar` up within a `Provider` and your `Login` within a `Consumer`. Let me know if that isn't clear enough.

Comment: its better to use redux in such scenarios, as that makes communication between components very easy

Comment: Yes,that's what I am going to do. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think for this simple paradigm you'll need to go through all the hassle of setting redux up(I love Redux, but sometimes we don't have to use it)

Here's how you could implement it with the new `context`.

[image: Edit React Hooks]

> It's farily simple and nice to use. Check it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#api)
>   Let me know if that isn't clear.

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: nice solution. Clean and simple

Comment: Thanks! I really like this new api and how it all flows together :)

Comment: Oh thank you @KhurshidAnsari for your comment, I have no idea why the url got messed up!!! Just updated it:)

Answer (score 0):

Login should be a children component of MyAppBar. Then you could pass function handleLogin as a props to Login.

Comment: Hi, the poster has trouble because the components cant be child components.

Answer (score 0):

You should use REDUX.

Mostly because it lets you have a state that any component can read or can be synced with.

I rarely use react's state/setState.

In most cases redux state is good to change/watch.

Comment: That's what I am going to do! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

its better to use redux in such scenarios, as that makes communication between components very easy. Else if you want to go the hard way, then create a parent component, that will wrap both login and MyAppBar.

```
  class ParentComp extends Component{
      constructor(props){ 
         super(props);
         this.state={
             isLoggedIn:false
         };
        this.setLoginState=this.setLoginState.bind(this);
      }
      setLoginState(value){
          this.setState({isLoggedIn:value});
      }

       render(){
         return(<div>
                   <MyAppBar isLoggedIn={this.state.isLoggedIn} />
               <Route path={path} render={props=><Login {..props} setLoginState={this.setLoginState}/>}/>
                </div>);
       }
  }
```

in your LoginComponent call the setLoginState method

```
   this.props.setLoginState(true);
```

and in your myappbar component
 use the isLoggedIn prop to render conditionally

```
   renderLogin(){
     if(this.props.isLoggedIn){ 
          // return loggedin jsx
     }else{
         return the alternative
     }
   }
```

Comment: I am going to use Redux, but thank you very much for this alternative solution.